# How do I scrape images using Python while ignoring their height & width in the URL?

Tags: python, url, urllib

I'm attempting to write a Python script to download images from an API.
The API returns the images in a format like this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/media/GetImage?ID=98383838&imageName=03833883.jpg&width=640&height=480`
```

with each image on a new line. I'm trying to use urllib, but struggling to figure out how to ignore the width/height processing each jpg, as I want the full size images rather than the 640x480's.

I've been testing with the following:

```
import urllib
import re

input_file = open('imgurls.txt','r')
x=0
for line in input_file:
    URL= line

    urllib.urlretrieve(URL, str(x) + ".jpg")
    x+=1
```

I'm not sure how to approach the width/height issue.
I believe I should use rsplit but not really sure.
I'll also need to move to the next line if the line it is reading is not a URL to avoid errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split off the last two query parameters from the URL, then join the URL back.

```
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/media/GetImage?ID=98383838&imageName=03833883.jpg&width=640&height=480'
full_img_url = '&'.join(url.split('&')[:-2])

# 'https://stackoverflow.com/media/GetImage?ID=98383838&imageName=03833883.jpg'
```

This assumes width and height are always last.

Answer (score 2):

cricket_007's answer looks great to me. A slightly more robust approach could be to use `urlparse` to break up the URL, remove the query parameters you don't need and reconstruct it:

```
import urlparse
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/media/GetImage?ID=98383838&imageName=03833883.jpg&width=640&height=480'
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
query = parsed.query
parsed_query = urlparse.parse_qs(query)
parsed_query.pop('width', None)
parsed_query.pop('height', None)
result = urlparse.urlunparse((parsed.scheme, parsed.netloc, parsed.path, parsed.params, urllib.urlencode(parsed_query, True), parsed.fragment))
```